# Python executes "len" function outside of if statement but not inside

Tags: python

I am somewhat new to python.  I'm writing a small script to use our tools api to help do some network mapping and discovery in our environment. The script is just about done but I've hit a weird situation where I cannot get a function to return anything after going through an if statement.

```
x = len(info['resources'][i]['addresses'])
if 'ip' in info['resources'][i]['addresses']:
    x = len(info['resources'][i]['addresses'])
    for j in range(0, x):
         ip.append(info['resources'][i]['addresses'][j]['ip'])
```

in this code I need to use the `len(info['resources'][i]['addresses']` in the for loop to accurately pull the ips.  The first function call before the if statement will return the correct number, but the second one (yes, I've verified that the if statement is triggering) does not work.  Doesn't matter if it is placed like that or if placed in the range(0, ...) statement. Is there something that I'm just not seeing or something that is unique to python that won't let that trigger?

Sample of the json I'm going through:

```
{
    "resources": [
        {
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "ip": "172.16.x.xx",
                    "mac": "00:0C:29:xx:xx:xx"
                }
            ],
```

Comment: I don't think the `if` condition will ever be true. `info['resources'][i]['addresses']` is a list of dictionaries, not a single dictionary.

Comment: You are checking if `ip'` is in a list of `dict`s, not if `ip` is a key in any particular `dict`. Your `if` condition is always false.

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):` Use `for item in list:`

Comment: You need add an index in `address` list. For example `if 'ip' in info['resources'][i]['addresses'][0]:`

Comment: @depperm `thing in dictionary` is the same as `thing in dictionary.keys()`

Comment: "yes, I've verified that the if statement is triggering" -- how so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not testing if `ip` is in the dictionary, you're testing whether `ip` is in the list. Since the list contains dictionaries, they'll never be equal to a string.

The `if` statement should be inside the loop so you can test the specific element.

```
for addr in info['resources'][i]['addresses']:
    if 'ip' in addr:
        ip.append(addr['ip'])
```

Comment: What I need is for it to get the ip if it is in there, and to skip it so that it if it doesn't.  I have been able to solve my problem based on the first part of your comment but I would like to understand the "all" function solution better.  That only comes true if every dictionary in the list of dictionaries has "ip" correct?

Comment: Then you should put the `if` statement inside the loop, not the other way around.